# Linear equation word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

"Separate $147$ into two numbers so that the larger number exceeds three times the smaller by $27.$"

I'm supposed to use only one variable, to devise an equation consistent with the above information, then solve for the larger and smaller numbers that add up to $147$.

Comment: Call the smaller $s$.  write an equation for the larger, but hide it from your teacher. Then substitute that into larger+smaller=147 and claim victory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $x$ the larger number; then $147-x$ is the smaller number.
Since the larger number exceeds three times the smaller number by $27$, We have the equation $$x = 3(147-x) +27$$
 $$\text{or}\,4x = (3\cdot 147) +27$$
 I'm assuming you can solve the above equation for $x$, the larger number, and then the smaller number will be $147 - x$.